# Text is overlapping with arrows in gojs tree diagram

Tags: javascript, html, gojs

I'm currently creating a tree structure chart using gojs

I'm facing issue in arranging the nodes, the text is overlapping with arrows

Suggestion/Help much appreciated

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
$(go.Node, "Auto", {
    movable: true
  },
  $(go.Panel, "Vertical",

    $(go.Panel, "Auto", {
        background: "white"
      }, {
        portId: ""
      },
      $(go.Shape, "Circle", {
          strokeWidth: 4,
          margin: go.Margin.parse("10 5 10 5"),
          height: 75,
          width: 75,
          cursor: "pointer"
        },
        new go.Binding("fill", "color"), new go.Binding("stroke", "strokeColor")
      ),

      $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
        $(go.Picture, {
          source: "https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/05/icon.png",
          background: "white",
          width: 25,
          height: 25
        })
      )
    ),

    $(go.Panel, "Auto",
      $(go.TextBlock, {
          margin: 5,
          font: '14px "Open Sans", sans-serif'
        },
        new go.Binding("text", "name"))
    )
  )

);
```

My working [fiddle is available](http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/s0zk5f34/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the assignment:

```
{
  portId: ""
},
```

Read the discussion at: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/ports.html#SinglePorts, except that instead of having the **Panel** holding the circle **Shape** and **Picture** be the port, you want the default behavior where the whole **Node** acts as the port.

Comment: No, I want the text outside of the circle only.

I need another help, I'm trying to display another text in right side of the circle. How can I achieve that?